# Find index of array class

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I got stuck at finding my value index in the array. I figured out how to check if my value exists in the array, but how to find index, i don't know. I searched through google, tried all other functions, didn't get any progress. So it would be awesome if anybody could explain and give some examples how to achieve my wanted results, thanks for your time.

```
public phrases[] sentences = new phrases[1];

    // STRUCT
public struct phrases
{
    public string key;
    public string value;
}

Array.FindIndex(sentences, key => key.value == "kaka");
```

Comment: Learn to use the plain old `for` cycle…

Comment: Doesn't `Array.FindIndex(sentences, key => key.value == "kaka")` return the index??? I mean, `int index = Array.FindIndex(sentences, key => key.value == "kaka");` looks like what you need.

Comment: it returns -1 or 0, but not the actual index in which the value was found.

Comment: because your array has only one element (`new phrases[1]`) so it can return 0 (first and only index of your array) when it finds it or -1 when it does not

Comment: 'Ondrej Tucny' i am avoiding it for my own reasons. :) Thanks for opinion. dkozl, yes that was the problem, but got another one, it find's only last key in my case, so if i have 4 values, it will find 4 and nothing more if i search for 2,1,3 it won't find anything it will give me -1? Can you explain why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this method:

```
int getIndexMethod(phrases[] array, string valueToFind)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i].value == valueToFind)
        {
           return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And, by the way, your:

```
Array.FindIndex(sentences, key => key.value == "kaka");
```

should also do work well, just return it's value to some variable, like:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(sentences, key => key.value == "kaka");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working this way :

```
phrases[] sentences = new phrases[4];

sentences[3] = new phrases() { key = "kaka", value = "kaka" };

var index =  Array.FindIndex(sentences, key => key.value == "kaka");
```